# No GPU Support using OpenCv 2.4.10 + Cuda 7.5 + W10

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2013, windows-10

**Im trying to get GPU up and running using:**

- OpenCv 2.4.10
- Visual Studio 2013
- Cuda toolkit 7.5  (cuda samples tested and running)
- Windows 10 x64
- Lenovo Y50 with NVIDIA GEFORCE GTX 860M

**I have compiled OpenCv using CMake with WITH_CUDA=ON,  and then installed the libraries by opening OpenCv.sln and built ALLBUILD and INSTALL projects.**

**Set my Project configuration as:**

- VC++ Directories

  - include Directories:

    - C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v7.5\include
    - C:\OpenCv\opencv\build\install\include (Contains the compiled libraries)
    - C:\OpenCv\opencv\build\include
- Linker-general-Additional libraries

  - C:\OpenCv\opencv\build\x64\vc12\lib
  - C:\OpenCv\opencv\build\install\x64\vc12\lib
- Linker-input-Additional Depencies

  - opencv_calib3d2410d.lib
  - opencv_contrib2410d.lib
  - opencv_core2410d.lib
  - opencv_features2d2410d.lib
  - opencv_flann2410d.lib
  - opencv_gpu2410d.lib
  - opencv_highgui2410d.lib
  - opencv_imgproc2410d.lib
  - opencv_legacy2410d.lib
  - opencv_ml2410d.lib
  - opencv_nonfree2410d.lib
  - opencv_objdetect2410d.lib
  - opencv_ocl2410d.lib
  - opencv_photo2410d.lib
  - opencv_stitching2410d.lib
  - opencv_superres2410d.lib
  - opencv_ts2410d.lib
  - opencv_video2410d.lib
  - opencv_videostab2410d.lib

**My environment variables:**
Path= C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing;Toolkit\CUDA\v7.5;C:\OpenCv\opencv\build\install\x64\vc12\bin;C:\OpenCv\opencv\build\x64\vc12\bin

**Testing code:**

```
   #include "opencv2\opencv.hpp"
   #include "opencv2\gpu\gpu.hpp"

    using namespace cv::gpu;
    using namespace std;

    int main() {
        {
        setDevice(0); 
        int gpu = getCudaEnabledDeviceCount();
        cout << gpu ;
        system("pause");
        return 0;
        }

}in
```

But setDevice throws

> no GPU support (The library is compiled without CUDA support) in
>   EmptyDeviceInfoFuncTable::setDevice, file
>   c:\builds\2_4_PackSlave-win64-vc12-shared\opencv\dynamicuda\include\opencv2/dynamiccuda/dynamicuda.hpp.
>   line 84

and if i comment setDevice(0) the gpu is still not detected, getCudaEnabledDeviceCount returns 0.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that Opencv 2.4.10 supports CUDA 4.2 and my video card is compatible only with CUDA 6.5 and 7.5 , I solved by installing OpenCV 3.0.0