# OpenCV 4.4.0 no built-in GPU support?

Tags: opencv

I am having trouble playing with GPU support in OpenCV 4.4.0 downloaded from https://opencv.org/releases/. The changelog has 23 hits for `CUDA`. The last one in under 4.4.0. Yet when I run a simple C++ sample that does:

```
cv::cuda::getCudaEnabledDeviceCount()
```

I get a ZERO. I have then tried to call `setDevice(0)` as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32774673/no-gpu-support-using-opencv-2-4-10-cuda-7-5-w10) and the result was the following exception.

```
OpenCV(4.4.0) C:\build\master_winpack-build-win64-vc15\opencv\modules\core\include\opencv2/core/private.cuda.hpp:106: error: (-216:No CUDA support) The library is compiled without CUDA support in function 'throw_no_cuda'
```

This seems to indicate there is **NO** CUDA support in the pre-built OpenCV. Must I build it myself? Are there trusted Windows binaries with CUDA support?

I have even installed the latest CUDA Toolkit (available at `C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.0`) and made sure to update system environment variables but to no avail.

Yet, even before installing the CUDA Toolkit, I was able to run `opencv_version_win32.exe` from `opencv\build\x64\vc15\bin` which gave me the (relevant) output below.

Is my card `GeForce GTX 980M` too old? Are there some additional setup steps I need to take before invoking `cv::cuda::getCudaEnabledDeviceCount()`?

```
OpenCL Platforms:
    NVIDIA CUDA
        dGPU: GeForce GTX 980M (OpenCL 1.2 CUDA)
Current OpenCL device:
    Type = dGPU
    Name = GeForce GTX 980M
    Version = OpenCL 1.2 CUDA
    Driver version = 451.67
    Address bits = 64
    Compute units = 12
    Max work group size = 1024
    Local memory size = 48 KB
    Max memory allocation size = 2 GB
    Double support = Yes
    Host unified memory = No
    Device extensions:
        cl_khr_global_int32_base_atomics
        cl_khr_global_int32_extended_atomics
        cl_khr_local_int32_base_atomics
        cl_khr_local_int32_extended_atomics
        cl_khr_fp64
        cl_khr_byte_addressable_store
        cl_khr_icd
        cl_khr_gl_sharing
        cl_nv_compiler_options
        cl_nv_device_attribute_query
        cl_nv_pragma_unroll
        cl_nv_d3d10_sharing
        cl_khr_d3d10_sharing
        cl_nv_d3d11_sharing
        cl_nv_copy_opts
        cl_nv_create_buffer
        cl_khr_int64_base_atomics
        cl_khr_int64_extended_atomics
    Has AMD Blas = No
    Has AMD Fft = No
    Preferred vector width char = 1
    Preferred vector width short = 1
    Preferred vector width int = 1
    Preferred vector width long = 1
    Preferred vector width float = 1
    Preferred vector width double = 1
OpenCV's HW features list:
    ID=  1 (MMX) -> ON
    ID=  2 (SSE) -> ON
    ID=  3 (SSE2) -> ON
    ID=  4 (SSE3) -> ON
    ID=  5 (SSSE3) -> ON
    ID=  6 (SSE4.1) -> ON
    ID=  7 (SSE4.2) -> ON
    ID=  8 (POPCNT) -> ON
    ID=  9 (FP16) -> ON
    ID= 10 (AVX) -> ON
    ID= 11 (AVX2) -> ON
    ID= 12 (FMA3) -> ON
Total available: 12
Parallel framework: ms-concurrency (nthreads=8)
```

Here is the output of `cv:: getBuildInformation()`

```
General configuration for OpenCV 4.4.0 =====================================
  Version control:               4.4.0

  Platform:
    Timestamp:                   2020-07-17T22:58:08Z
    Host:                        Windows 10.0.18363 AMD64
    CMake:                       3.16.4
    CMake generator:             Visual Studio 15 2017
    CMake build tool:            C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Professional/MSBuild/15.0/Bin/MSBuild.exe
    MSVC:                        1916

  CPU/HW features:
    Baseline:                    SSE SSE2 SSE3
      requested:                 SSE3
    Dispatched code generation:  SSE4_1 SSE4_2 FP16 AVX AVX2 AVX512_SKX
      requested:                 SSE4_1 SSE4_2 AVX FP16 AVX2 AVX512_SKX
      SSE4_1 (15 files):         + SSSE3 SSE4_1
      SSE4_2 (1 files):          + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2
      FP16 (0 files):            + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 AVX
      AVX (4 files):             + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 AVX
      AVX2 (29 files):           + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 FMA3 AVX AVX2
      AVX512_SKX (4 files):      + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 FMA3 AVX AVX2 AVX_512F AVX512_COMMON AVX512_SKX

  C/C++:
    Built as dynamic libs?:      YES
    C++ standard:                11
    C++ Compiler:                C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Professional/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.16.27023/bin/Hostx86/x64/cl.exe  (ver 19.16.27042.0)
    C++ flags (Release):         /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W4 /GR  /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /Gy /bigobj /Oi  /fp:precise     /EHa /wd4127 /wd4251 /wd4324 /wd4275 /wd4512 /wd4589 /MP2  /MD /O2 /Ob2 /DNDEBUG 
    C++ flags (Debug):           /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W4 /GR  /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /Gy /bigobj /Oi  /fp:precise     /EHa /wd4127 /wd4251 /wd4324 /wd4275 /wd4512 /wd4589 /MP2  /MDd /Zi /Ob0 /Od /RTC1 
    C Compiler:                  C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Professional/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.16.27023/bin/Hostx86/x64/cl.exe
    C flags (Release):           /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3  /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /Gy /bigobj /Oi  /fp:precise     /MP2   /MD /O2 /Ob2 /DNDEBUG 
    C flags (Debug):             /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3  /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /Gy /bigobj /Oi  /fp:precise     /MP2 /MDd /Zi /Ob0 /Od /RTC1 
    Linker flags (Release):      /machine:x64  /INCREMENTAL:NO 
    Linker flags (Debug):        /machine:x64  /debug /INCREMENTAL 
    ccache:                      NO
    Precompiled headers:         NO
    Extra dependencies:
    3rdparty dependencies:

  OpenCV modules:
    To be built:                 calib3d core dnn features2d flann gapi highgui imgcodecs imgproc ml objdetect photo stitching video videoio world
    Disabled:                    python2 python3
    Disabled by dependency:      -
    Unavailable:                 java js ts
    Applications:                apps
    Documentation:               NO
    Non-free algorithms:         NO

  Windows RT support:            NO

  GUI: 
    Win32 UI:                    YES
    VTK support:                 NO

  Media I/O: 
    ZLib:                        build (ver 1.2.11)
    JPEG:                        build-libjpeg-turbo (ver 2.0.5-62)
    WEBP:                        build (ver encoder: 0x020f)
    PNG:                         build (ver 1.6.37)
    TIFF:                        build (ver 42 - 4.0.10)
    JPEG 2000:                   build Jasper (ver 1.900.1)
    OpenEXR:                     build (ver 2.3.0)
    HDR:                         YES
    SUNRASTER:                   YES
    PXM:                         YES
    PFM:                         YES

  Video I/O:
    DC1394:                      NO
    FFMPEG:                      YES (prebuilt binaries)
      avcodec:                   YES (58.54.100)
      avformat:                  YES (58.29.100)
      avutil:                    YES (56.31.100)
      swscale:                   YES (5.5.100)
      avresample:                YES (4.0.0)
    GStreamer:                   NO
    DirectShow:                  YES
    Media Foundation:            YES
      DXVA:                      YES

  Parallel framework:            Concurrency

  Trace:                         YES (with Intel ITT)

  Other third-party libraries:
    Intel IPP:                   2020.0.0 Gold [2020.0.0]
           at:                   C:/build/master_winpack-build-win64-vc15/build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_win/icv
    Intel IPP IW:                sources (2020.0.0)
              at:                C:/build/master_winpack-build-win64-vc15/build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_win/iw
    Eigen:                       NO
    Custom HAL:                  NO
    Protobuf:                    build (3.5.1)

  OpenCL:                        YES (NVD3D11)
    Include path:                C:/build/master_winpack-build-win64-vc15/opencv/3rdparty/include/opencl/1.2
    Link libraries:              Dynamic load

  Python (for build):            C:/utils/soft/python27-x64/python.exe

  Java:                          
    ant:                         C:/utils/soft/apache-ant-1.9.7/bin/ant.bat (ver 1.9.7)
    JNI:                         C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_112/include C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_112/include/win32 C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_112/include
    Java wrappers:               NO
    Java tests:                  NO

  Install to:                    C:/build/master_winpack-build-win64-vc15/install
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: That is strange. I've OpenCV 3.4 a while back with an old GeForce GT 750M and had no issues. Hopefully no major changes that caused some CUDA support to drop. I think Jozed is right: I wouldn't expect the prebuild c++ binaries to compiled with CUDA support. Can you please post the output of `cv:: getBuildInformation()` on your machine ? It should explicitly mention if it was built with CUDA or not

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza Amended the question with build info.

Comment: No mention of CUDA there...also notice no `opencv_contrib` modules either: looks like you will need to build OpenCV from source if you want CUDA support. You can see an example I ran [here](https://pastebin.com/ErNS3Kvv). Notice the many OpenCV CUDA modules(`cudaarithm cudabgsegm cudacodec cudafeatures2d cudafilters cudaimgproc cudalegacy cudaobjdetect cudaoptflow cudastereo cudawarping cudev`) and ` NVIDIA CUDA:                   YES (ver 10.0, CUFFT CUBLAS FAST_MATH)
    NVIDIA GPU arch:             101` of course. Follow Jozef's guides paying attention to differences on your machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to build your own libraries with CMAKE.
I am not sure if prebuilt binaries have CUDA setting enabled as default. With the CMAKE installation, customizing the library for a given computer environment is much better.

You can find some manuals on youtube.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TT3_dlPL4vo

https://jamesbowley.co.uk/build-opencv-4-0-0-with-cuda-10-0-and-intel-mkl-tbb-in-windows/

Comment: Not sure why the downvotes. You've got a +1 from me: great resources.
Maybe paste the snippet from James Bowley's article, the "OpenCV 4.0.0 with CUDA 10.0" section ? (The hope is that while the sites may go offline after a number of years, the essential bit of information will be preserved with your answer)